# Theorem about compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis

How could I proof the following?

Let, X, Y, Z be Banach spaces. If $A \in L(X,Y)$, $B \in L(X,Y)$ show that

A compact or B compact $\Rightarrow$ AB=BA compact

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $AB=BA?$.......

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is compact, then $A(B_X(0,1))$ is relatively compact i.e it is contained in a compact subset $C$ of $B$, $B(C)$ is compact since the image of a compact subset by a continuous map is compact, this implies that $BA(B_X(0,1))\subset B(C)$ is relatively compact.

Suppose that $B$ is compact, $A(B_X(0,1)))$ is bounded, since $A$  is bounded, this implies that $BA(B_X(0,1))$ is relatively compact since $B$ is a compact operator.